# ScrollBars not appearing in Safari

Tags: asp.net, .net, safari, scrollbars

My ASP.net app's scrollbars are working in IE, Firefox, and other browsers, but don't work in Safari.

This is the line of code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" Height="662px" ScrollBars="Auto" Width="702px"  style="float:left; position: relative; background-image: url('Images/LargeOffwhiteBox.png')" runat="server">
```

The page I am developing this for is here: http://www.icdpros.com/clients.aspx

Opening it in IE or Firefox shows a vertical scrollbar in the middle panel. Safari doesn't get a scrollbar and therefore can't be scrolled.

Does anybody know the solution to this?

Comment: Works in Safari 5.1 for Windows

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's the default behavior for Safari 5.1. Although it doesn't show overflow when you set overflow:auto, you can scroll using two fingers on the trackpad up and down, or with the mousewheel. As you scroll using these two methods, the scrollbar and thumb will appear. After starting to scroll as afore mentioned, you can then grab the scrollbar thumb with the cursor and drag it up and down. A few moments after scroll, the scrollbar fades away automatically until the user again makes and attempt to scroll with the trackpad or mousewheel.